# paypal later button not being displayed

Tags: javascript, paypal, sdk

I have tried the following paypal code but it is not showing paypal later button. Is there any conditional or only us geo location will it show

```
  // Loop over each funding source / payment method
paypal_sdk.getFundingSources().forEach(function(fundingSource) {

    // Initialize the buttons
    var button = paypal_sdk.Buttons({
        fundingSource: fundingSource
    });

    // Check if the button is eligible
    if (button.isEligible()) {

        // Render the standalone button for that funding source
        button.render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various factors determine the Pay Later eligibility, such as the currency of the transaction and the location of the buyer and the intent and it not being a vault or subscription transaction. Try with currency USD and a buyer located in the US, for example -- in sandbox (not live) mode you can pass the parameter `&buyer-country=US` in the SDK script's query string parameters for test purposes.

Comment: After adding buyer-country=us i can see the paypal later button thanks